# Passing a new value into without changing source file, but adding to install to remote server

Tags: elasticsearch, powershell-3.0

Change a value in a winlogbeat.yml as it is passed to serveral remote servers. Here is the value to change > hosts: localhost:5044 and when script kicks off on remote server it is to change to >lp-index-QA.QA.com:9999

Here is the script I wrote.. no failures but does not pass the new value to remote server>>

```
#ExecutionPolicy 
     Set-ExecutionPolicy -Force Unrestricted

#DC = (facter datacenter) | Out-String
    $DC = 'parpr1'

    $QAhost = @("hosts: lp-index-QA.QA.com:9999", "`r`nhosts: localhost:5044")
    $PRODhost = @("hosts: lp-index-PROD.PROD.com:9999", "`r`nhosts:   localhost:5044")
    $file = 'C:\winlogbeat-1.2.3-windows\winlogbeat.yml'

    if ($DC -eq "QA")
 {
     Write-Host "Datacenter is $DC"

     Add-Content -PassThru -Path "$file" -Value "hosts: lp-index-QA.QA.com:9999"   
 }

      if ($DC -eq "PROD")

 {
      Write-Host "Datacenter is $DC"

      Add-Content -PassThru -Path "$file" -Value "hosts: lp-index- PROD.PROD.com:9999"   
 }


# delete service if it already exists
      if (Get-Service winlogbeat -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
      $service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter     "name='winlogbeat'"
      $service.StopService()
      Start-Sleep -s 1
      $service.delete()
}

    $workdir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

# create new service
    New-Service -name winlogbeat `
      -displayName winlogbeat `
      -binaryPathName "`"$workdir\\winlogbeat.exe`" -c   `"$workdir\\winlogbeat.yml`""

#pause 5s
    Start-Sleep -s 10

#Startingserver 

    Start-service winlogbeat
```